# How to find $\sin\left(-\frac{11\pi}{12}\right)$ from the unit circle?

Tags: trigonometry

I Want Above To Be In Unit Circle.... unit circle. like convert $\frac{\pi}{3}$ to $\frac{4\pi}{12}$ to make it same denom... and then do stuff.... i tried to do with $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (convert to $\frac{6\pi}{12}$) and $\frac{\pi}{3}$ (convert to $\frac{4\pi}{12}$) ... but it only gives you $\frac{10\pi}{12}$.. Please Help. I DO NOT want the anwser only.. i want how you did it.. i already have anwser as it is a study guide but i want to know how you did it.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You basically need to find some linear combination of $\frac{6\pi}{12}$, $\frac{3\pi}{12}$, and $\frac{2\pi}{12}$ to equal $-\frac{11\pi}{12}$...which means $6i + 3k + 2j = 11$...incidentally $6 + 3 + 2$ works.

Comment: Notice that $\frac{11\pi}{12} = \frac{8\pi}{12} + \frac{3\pi}{12} = \frac{2\pi}{3} + \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Nope I didnt Notice That @N.F.Taussig .. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Step 1: Convert to degrees, your intuition will be more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sin(-x) = -\sin x$, 
$$\sin\left(-\frac{11\pi}{12}\right) = -\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{12}\right)$$
We can compute $\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{12}\right)$ using the sum of angles formula for sine.
\begin{align*}
\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{12}\right) & = \sin\left(\frac{8\pi}{12} + \frac{3\pi}{12}\right)\\
& = \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3} + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\
& = \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\
& = \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) + \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{4} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2}}{4}
\end{align*}
Hence, 
$$\sin\left(-\frac{11\pi}{12}\right) = -\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{12}\right) = -\left(\frac{\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2}}{4}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{6}}{4}$$

Comment: OMG I did a + instead of a - .... Whats wrong with me... Im Afraid Ill Make these dum mistakes at quiz...

Comment: For practice, you can do the problem by using the observation that $$\frac{11\pi}{12} = \frac{9\pi}{12} + \frac{2\pi}{12} = \frac{3\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi}{6}$$  It also gives you a way of checking your result.

Comment: Oh ok.. N.f... I need to know both degrees and radians for quiz.. by any chance you can do me a favor and do sin(105degrees) please? That would be really helpfull! Thankyou!

Comment: \begin{align*} \sin(105^\circ) & = \sin(60^\circ + 45^\circ)\\ & = \sin(60^\circ)\cos(45^\circ) + \cos(60^\circ)\sin(45^\circ)\\ & = \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\\ & = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{4} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\\ & = \frac{\sqrt{6} + \sqrt{2}}{4} \end{align*}

Comment: Your A Genius....

Comment: Not really, but doing these problems does take practice.

Comment: Ok N.f i got this problem tan(5pi/12) dont tell me anwser but i cant find what adds to it... once i find that.. all rest is easy stuff..

Comment: Wait NVM pi/4 and pi/6 .... Im Dum.....

Answer (score 3):

Since the sine function is odd and fulfills $\sin(t)=\sin(\pi-t)$ we have:
$$\sin\left(-\frac{11\pi}{12}\right)=-\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{12}\right)=-\sin\frac{\pi}{12}$$
and since $\frac{\pi}{12}$ is an acute angle, by the half-angle formula $\sin\frac{t}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos t}{2}}$ we get:
$$\sin\left(-\frac{11\pi}{12}\right)=-\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\frac{\pi}{6}}{2}}=\color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}.$$

Comment: i dont see how you got pi/6 please explain! I need to get ready for quiz :( .. By How you got pi/6 i mean like you did cos pi/6 how did you get that pi/6?

Comment: @AmanuelBogale: $\frac{\pi}{12}$ is half $\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Comment: how did you get pi/2 from 11pi/12 ???

Comment: There is no $\frac{\pi}{2}$ in my answer. Please read it carefully.

Comment: sorry i meant ... how did you get pi/12

Comment: @AmanuelBogale: It is written in the very first line. I applied $\sin(-t)=-\sin(t)$ and $\sin(t)=\sin(\pi-t)$.

Comment: i understand the first thing you did by putting the - out, its called even-odd property but... we didnt learn the second thing you did in class... you have another way?  Please Help!

Comment: @AmanuelBogale: I am not in your class so I do not know what tools are supposed to be used, but it is trivial that the only knowledge of the value of $\sin$ and $\cos$ at the multiples of $\frac{\pi}{6}$ is not enough to compute $\sin\frac{\pi}{12}$.

Comment: However, you may use the fact that $\frac{\pi}{12}=\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{4}$ and use the addition formula for the sine function.

Comment: "However, you may use the fact that π12=π3−π4π12=π3−π4 and use the addition formula for the sine function" - Jack  .. How?

Comment: $\sin\frac{\pi}{12} = \sin\frac{\pi}{3}\cos\frac{\pi}{4}-\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\cos\frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: Ok i think i will have to ask my teacher that question at the morning... Anways one more question please. Do you know how to do sin 105degrees? Its obviously not on the unit circle

Comment: Same way. $\frac{7\pi}{12}=\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{4}$, so $$\sin\frac{7\pi}{12}=\sin\frac{\pi}{3}\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\cos \frac{\pi}{3}.$$

Comment: You see i cant ask your help in the quiz... so like how did you come up with 7pi/12? Please Help!

Comment: @AmanuelBogale: $105^\circ = \frac{7}{12}\cdot 180^\circ = \frac{7\pi}{12}$. Do you know the conversion between degrees and radians?

Comment: Its just that how did you get 7/12... how did the math work in your head... Man im not feeling too good about this quiz...

Comment: @AmanuelBogale: $105^\circ$ is seven times $15^\circ$ and $15^\circ$ is the twelfth part of a straight angle ($180^\circ$).

Comment: You see.... im not a matamtecian.. and that logic is certaintly not gonna come to my head if i was quizzed like that question..